# How to disable Samba on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, samba

I need to disable (not uninstall) Samba on Ubuntu 12.04 server but I cant see any link in rc2.d directory. How Samba is starting after reboot? How to disable smbd/nmbd daemon?? What is winbind?

```
root@newnagios:~# ll /etc/rc2.d/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Aug 15 16:23 ./
drwxr-xr-x 101 root root 4096 Aug 16 12:13 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  677 Jul 26  2012 README
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   17 Aug  4 20:34 S20postfix -> ../init.d/postfix*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   15 Aug 12 15:55 S20snmpd -> ../init.d/snmpd*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   17 Aug  4 20:34 S20winbind -> ../init.d/winbind*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   13 Aug  5 12:42 S23ntp -> ../init.d/ntp*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   15 Aug  4 18:07 S25mdadm -> ../init.d/mdadm*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   15 Aug  4 20:34 S50rsync -> ../init.d/rsync*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   19 Aug  4 20:34 S70dns-clean -> ../init.d/dns-clean*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Aug  4 20:34 S70pppd-dns -> ../init.d/pppd-dns*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   14 Aug  4 22:03 S75sudo -> ../init.d/sudo*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   17 Aug  4 20:34 S91apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   21 Aug  4 20:35 S99grub-common -> ../init.d/grub-common*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Aug  4 18:06 S99ondemand -> ../init.d/ondemand*
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   18 Aug  4 18:06 S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local*
```

Answer (score 20):

Type the following command to stop smbd service.

**To Stop Samba:**

```
sudo service smbd stop
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd stop
```

**To Start Samba:**

```
sudo service smbd start
```

or

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd start
```

**To remove it from rc.d file use the command**

```
sudo update-rc.d -f smbd remove
```

**To restore it to rc.d use the command**

```
sudo update-rc.d smbd defaults
```

Comment: Yes, but it works only till reboot. I need to disable Samba service. In Ubuntu 10 there was link in rc2.d `S20samba -> ../init.d/samba`

Comment: Try this `sudo update-rc.d -f smbd remove`

Comment: Wasn't Samba converted to Upstart job or something?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and there is no `smbd` anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to disable the Samba service:

```
update-rc.d -f smbd defaults
```

Or use this for the Upstart service:

```
echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/smbd.conf
```

Or you can install and check for services:

```
apt-get install rcconf
```